# Waterfall across Date range by Date in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I have a value across date ranges for subscriptions and want to calculate revenue by month (by day rolled up to month) and if it was a 100 day subscription for 100 dollars starting on Jan 3rd, going to Apr 12, then I would want 29 for Jan, 28 for Feb, 31 for March, and 12 for Apr. Does that make sense? I have a start date, an End Date, a total Value, And am blanking on how to make that into what I want. There's a large number of records, and I originally thought just creating a temp table with all the records as single entries, date and value, and then was going to pivot it, but when looping through, I ran out of memory (millions of records for multiple days all being added) I am trying to create this in SQL. Thanks

Sample Data

```
StartDate               EndDate                 Total
2020-06-14 00:00:00.000 2020-07-13 00:00:00.000 50.74
2020-06-20 00:00:00.000 2020-07-19 00:00:00.000 28.04
2020-06-29 00:00:00.000 2020-06-29 00:00:00.000 .4
2020-06-29 00:00:00.000 2020-07-28 00:00:00.000 47.82
```

Output

```
Jun   July
28.75 21.99
10.28 17.76
.4    0 
3.19  44.63
```

Comment: Sample data, and expected results will help us help you, but also you might well want to consider making yourself a Calendar Table.

Comment: Join a calendar table on between start and end of each row, divide amount by number of days. Then group by year and month of the calendar.

Comment: Joining to a calendar is going to explode the size of the table, I have millions of records some spanning years, so that will take millions and make it billions or records. I am not sure this will be able to work

Comment: A month calendar table won't be anywhere near so bad though if you just want to aggregate months. 12 months x 20 years is only 240. Just need to make sure you do the division correctly

Answer (score 0):

given your sample data, and assuming your need is as simple as that, you can use EOMONTH function to compute the number of days left till end of month -- so you can avoid any join nor pivot

```
select *,[a+b] = a+b
        ,[Jun = a/(a+b)] = cast(Total * a * 1.00/(a+b) as numeric(9,2)) 
        ,[Jul = b/(a+b)] = cast(Total * b * 1.00/(a+b) as numeric(9,2))
from (values(cast('20200614 00:00:00.000' as date),cast('20200713 00:00:00.000' as date),50.74),('20200620 00:00:00.000','20200719 00:00:00.000',28.04),('20200629 00:00:00.000','20200629 00:00:00.000',.4),('20200629 00:00:00.000','20200728 00:00:00.000',47.82)
     )a(StartDate,EndDate,Total)
outer apply(select  
                 [a] = case when datediff(month,StartDate,EndDate)>0 then DATEDIFF(DAY,StartDate,EOMONTH(StartDate))+1 else DATEDIFF(DAY,StartDate,EndDate)+1 end
                ,[b] = case when datediff(month,StartDate,EndDate)>0 then DAY(EndDate)  else 0 end
            )calc
```

output:

```
StartDate   EndDate     Total   a   b   a+b Jun = a/(a+b)   Jul = b/(a+b)
2020-06-14  2020-07-13  50.74   17  13  30  28.75           21.99
2020-06-20  2020-07-19  28.04   11  19  30  10.28           17.76
2020-06-29  2020-06-29  0.40    1   0   1   0.40            0.00
2020-06-29  2020-07-28  47.82   2   28  30  3.19            44.63
```